# Expo React Not Building

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

I am using the eas cli to build my project, I can confirm I successfully logged in via eas login and it's giving me the following error: `Entity not authorized: AccountEntity[XXX] (viewer = RegularUserViewerContext[XXX], action = READ, ruleIndex = -1) Request ID: XXX` I am trying to target ios platform. One thing I should mention is I built the project before with my other account successfully for android, and logged into another to target ios. What could be wrong?

logged into my account successfully